# Chart in BIRT report is not showing

Tags: java, charts, jboss7.x, birt, ear

I am using birt 4.3 and jboss 7 , i have deployed my EAR on jboss, report is showing everything except chart there is no error on console as well. where can be issue ?

Comment: What type of report are you generating? HTML? PDF?

Comment: it is not showing in any format.

Comment: I understand that graph was working from birt developer (eclipse)? Do you have any other kind of graphics (for example image) in your template? Are they working?

Comment: report is working perfect from birt viewer but when the same report i m keeping it in my project and depolying my EAR and running it report is showing the table but not chart.